# How to make a call to oauth API from java code to generate access token?

Tags: java, spring, curl, oauth

I am a newbie to oauth, in my project I have an api from which we are generating Access Token, so far project was using curl to generate access token but now we have decided to use java to do the same.

**curl command**

```
curl -k https:/monkeyman/oauth/oauth20/token -d client_id=<client_id> -d client_secret=<client_secret> -d grant_type=client_credentials
```

I have created a small spring boot project and now I am trying to create a template where user could directly hit my spring boot end point and can get access token, rather than using curl.

Answer (score 0):

So after some more exhaustive research I was able to crack it -

this function will generate the access token for me and I can autowire this bean to my actual service

```
public OAuth2RestTemplate monkeymanRestTemplate() {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails clientCredentialsResourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(env.getRequiredProperty("monkeyman.api.accessToken.url"));
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setClientId(env.getRequiredProperty("monkeyman.api.client.id"));
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setClientSecret(env.getRequiredProperty("monkeyman.api.client.secret"));
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(clientCredentialsResourceDetails);
    }
```

I can autowire the above bean to my service class,

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("monkeymanRestTemplate")
private RestTemplate monkeymanRestTemplate;
```

and pass it with the service call and which in return would also pass the oauth access token with the call.

```
ResponseEntity<MonkeyManSiting> report = monkeymanRestTemplate.report(fullApiUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity,
                MonkeyManSiting.class);
```